# Riffle plus Append to ListPlot data of different lengths

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Say I have a list

`a={{1},{1},{1,2},{1,2}}`

and I would like to make a ListPlot out of it, such that the value(s) stored as the elements of the array `a` are plotted at positions `x={x1,x2,x3,x4}`, i.e., I would like to plot the points `{{x1,1},{x2,1},{x3,1},{x3,2},{x4,1},{x4,2}}`

At the moment I'm doing this with this incredibly ugly function:

`ListPlot[Reverse /@ Flatten[Partition[#, 2] & /@ MapThread[Append[Riffle[#1, #2], #2] &, {a, x}], 1]]`

It works, but I can't imagine this is the best way. But `ListPlot` doesn't seem to be able to handle data with different lengths.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
MapThread[Thread[{#1, #2}] &, {x, a}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
(* {{x1, 1}, {x2, 1}, {x3, 1}, {x3, 2}, {x4, 1}, {x4, 2}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is fairly straigthforward!

Answer (score 5):

```
thread0 = Inner[Thread @* List, ##, Join] &;

thread0[x, a]
```

> ```
> {{x1, 1}, {x2, 1}, {x3, 1}, {x3, 2}, {x4, 1}, {x4, 2}}
> ```

```
t = {1, 3, 5, 15};

ListLinePlot[thread0[t, a]]
```

[image]

You can also use:

```
thread1 = Catenate @* Map[Thread] @* Thread @* List;

thread1[x, a]
```

> ```
>  {{x1, 1}, {x2, 1}, {x3, 1}, {x3, 2}, {x4, 1}, {x4, 2}}
> ```

and

```
thread2 = MapThread[Apply[Sequence] @* Thread @* List];

thread2[{x, a}]
```

> ```
>  {{x1, 1}, {x2, 1}, {x3, 1}, {x3, 2}, {x4, 1}, {x4, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Using `Splice` that was newly introduced in version 12.1:

```
Splice@*Thread /@ Transpose[{x, a}]

(* {{x1, 1}, {x2, 1}, {x3, 1}, {x3, 2}, {x4, 1}, {x4, 2}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

A variation on other answers:

```
 MapThread[##&@@Thread[{##}]&,{x,a}]
```

> {{x1, 1}, {x2, 1}, {x3, 1}, {x3, 2}, {x4, 1}, {x4, 2}}